# Dashboard using Azure DevOps Services REST API

Tags: azure, rest, api, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We are working on building report/dashboard which helps to find the number of code commits, number of pull requests per day, within a particular range etc. We are using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

- Is there any existing product (Both paid and free) available?
- What is the right REST API to get the number of files/lines added per commit, per PR

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a [`rest API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) available,

- You can use Pull Requests - [`Get Pull Requests`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and filter out the results by Date
- Number of lines added per commit can be obtained using by [Get Commmits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)